# QGIS capture mouse point creation in python plugin

Tags: qgis

I'm creating a plugin in QGIS where I want to limit the possibilities for the user.

I have a function that creates a temporary line, adds it to the layers, puts it in `Editing` and `add line feature` mode:

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "Segment", "memory")
# Enter editing mode
vl.startEditing()
# add fields
pr = vl.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("id1",  QVariant.Int),
                    QgsField("id2", QVariant.Int) ] )
# adds a feature
fet = QgsFeature()
fet.setAttributes([1, 3])
pr.addFeatures( [ fet ] )
# Show in project
self.iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Now I want to "capture" the event when the user adds the second point to this layer, so I can commit "the editing" and add some stuff in a table. (So the user creates a simple line from point A to point B with two clicks)

Comment: Maybe a hint `QgsMapToolEmitPoint` : https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsMapToolEmitPoint.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hint, I looked around and found some parts and put together the following code:

```
class PointTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint): 
    canvasClicked = pyqtSignal('QgsPointXY')
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        super(QgsMapTool, self).__init__(canvas)

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        point_canvas_crs = event.mapPoint()
        self.canvasClicked.emit(point_canvas_crs)
```

The following is a part of my plugin class, where I have a button that says create line, which is connected to `add_new_line`)

```
def add_new_line(self):
    self.current_start_point = None
    self.point_layer = None
    self.mapTool = PointTool(self.iface.mapCanvas())
    self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(self.mapTool)
    self.mapTool.canvasClicked.connect(self.onMapClick)
    
def onMapClick(self, point):
    q_point = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(point.asWkt())
    crs = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().destinationCrs().authid()
    tr = QgsCoordinateTransform(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(crs),
                                QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326"),
                                QgsProject.instance())
    q_point.transform(tr)
    if self.current_start_point is None:
        self.create_point(q_point)
    else:
        self.create_line(q_point)

def create_point(self, point):
    self.point_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "StartPoint", "memory")
    prov = self.point_layer.dataProvider()
    self.point_layer.startEditing()
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setGeometry(point)
    prov.addFeatures([feat])
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.point_layer)
    self.current_start_point = point

def create_line(self, point):
    vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "Segment", "memory")
    vl.startEditing()
    fet = QgsFeature()
    start_point = QgsPoint(self.current_start_point.asPoint())
    end_point = QgsPoint(point.asPoint())
    fet.setGeometry(QgsLineString([start_point, end_point]))
    pr = vl.dataProvider()
    pr.addFeatures( [ fet ] )
    self.iface.actionToggleEditing().trigger()
    QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(self.point_layer)
    self.current_start_point = None
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```